# Obtaining the original coordinates of a ROI after cropping

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

The task I am trying to implement is as follows:

1. User selects region of interest.
2. This ROI is cropped from the original image and various image processing techniques are used to obtain the coordinates of several objects (their centroids) in the ROI.
3. The coordinates in the original frame are obtained by translating between the two coordinate systems.

My solution so far has been to use the corner coordinates of the original ROI rectangle to translate between the two systems:

```
rectObj = getrect(gca);
roi = rectObj.Position; % In [x0 y0 width height] format
% Obtain seed coordinates in the cropped image
seed_coords = [x y];
% Translate and obtain seed coordinates in the original image
new_seed_coords = seed_coords + [roi(1) roi(2)];
```

However, the centroids are now offset by a small amount which I assume is due to the ROI occurring across a pixel boundary which has some rounding effect on my values.

How can I get the *exact* coordinates (as precise as possible?) of the roi rectangle so I can get accurate coordinates in the original frame?

Comment: Define "small amount"

Comment: Subtracting [1 1] from the seed coordinates returns the centroid markers to the actual centroids of the objects to a good approximation (but not exact: i.e. the error magnitude is likely < 1 pixel).

Answer (score 1):

Using subpixel accuracy for user input makes no sense. It is even unlikely that your user hits a certain pixel accurately. Simply round those values to avoid any rounding issues in further steps.